# How to solve problem with gthr-default.h?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with `gthr-default`. I'm using `dev c++`. Any time I do something in it I get these errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bits\gthr-default.h    In function 'int __gthread_create(__gthread_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)':
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bits\gthr-default.h    [Error] 'NULL' was not declared in this scope

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Can you pose your code? At least [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You shouldn't include `gthr-default.h` in your own code, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` defined in stdef. Try to add `#include <cstddef>` before `gthr-default.h` include.

Comment: Put i dont even include it